# What is the policy about link targeting locked content?

Tags: discussion, citations, hyperlinks

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143086/11129) references https://www.dndbeyond.com/, which is an [official WoTC website](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/is-dd-beyond-an-official-rules-source). The problem we face with this content is that it is not accessible without a twitch account (afaik).

[image]

This defeat a huge part of this stack exchange. We could avoid this website but since it is seen as official, we would lost a lot of content. A solution could be to enforce to include the meaningful content into the post.

What is the policy about link targeting locked content?

Quite related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them

Comment: “A solution could be to enforce to include the meaningful content into the post.” That already should happen to the extent fair use permits it and citation requirements need it: quote a relevant passage from the rule you're mentioning to demonstrate your point, etc. It's not going to happen to the extent people copy material wholesale out of books or D&D Beyond so that others don't have to pay for the material since that would be piracy, e.g. no “I recommend using this monster from XGtE, it isn't freely available so let me quote its entire stat block for your usage.”

Comment: @doppelgreener thank you for the comment and the link. it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: FWIW, note that D&DB only requires an account for content that would require buying a book IRL to access; SRD content as well as some content (like [spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/erupting-earth) and [races](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/genasi)) from free publications like the Elemental Evil Player's Companion can be accessed without an account. For convenience's sake, we should be linking to the 'free' version of something if it exists and is identical to the paywall one.